# Query for accounts that equal M and where those M accounts contain "Ne" or "NY" in any other field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table with account number, account type and 50 columns with US states.

I want to run a query in access where it returns all Registered account types that are in NE or NY.  Each account type can have up to 50 different states in any State[1-50] column.

So I have:

```
Select *
FROM MSDAP
WHERE account_type = 'Registered' AND State1 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR 
      State2 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State3 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR 
      State4 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State5 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR 
      State6 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State6 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR 
      State7 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State8 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR 
      State9 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State9 IN ('NE', 'NY');
```

This obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What an awful data model.  You should have one row per state, rather than having the information spread across columns.

In any case, your problem is misplaced parentheses:

```
where account_type = 'Registered' AND
      (State1 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State2 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR
       State3 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State4 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR
       State5 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State6 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR 
       State6 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State7 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR   -- are you really checking `state6` again?
       State8 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR State9 IN ('NE', 'NY') OR 
       State9 IN ('NE', 'NY')  -- are you really checking `state9` again?
      )
```

Comment: I know - I'm working within the parameters I have. This worked - Thank you!